# How to add orderBy directive to relationship in a query?

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I have this:

```
type Client @guard {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  phone: String
  orders: [Order!]! @hasMany # How do i make it possible to order this array via client side?
}
```

```
extend type Query {
  client (
    id: ID! @eq
  ): Client @find
}
```

I would like to do something like that:

```
{
  client (id: 10) {
    orders (orderBy: ....) {
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried to add `@orderBy` on `orders` field  but it doesn't seems to work, is it possible to do in lighthouse-php?

Answer (score -1):

@orderBy directive let you specify a relation you can order your query from. [See the documentation](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/digging-deeper/ordering.html#client-controlled-ordering)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31231694)